# Increment for loop by date

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to increment date by new date. but it is not showing any result.

```
$ed = strtotime($endDate);
for ($i = $ed; $i <= strtotime($today); $i = $ed) {
    $toArray['d'] = $ed;
    $startDate = date('y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($endDate)));
    $endDate = date('y-m-d', strtotime("+13 day", strtotime($startDate)));
    $ed = strtotime($endDate);
}
```

It is not working.
Whats wrong..?

Comment: Your logic is wrong `$i = $ed;` initilisation and `$i = $ed;` condition again.

Comment: For loop syntax is wrong. check purpose of first,second and third statement of for loop.

Comment: Since this is a Laravel tagged question, why not just the Carbon libraries that built into the Framework?

Comment: well code is working now... Syntax is right...Nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $endDate='2017-06-21';
        $endDate='2017-05-05';
        $ed = strtotime($endDate);
        for($i = $ed; $i >= strtotime($today); $i = $ed ){
            $toArray['d'] = $ed;
            $startDate = date('y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($endDate)));
            $endDate = date('y-m-d', strtotime("+13 day", strtotime($startDate)));
            $ed = strtotime($endDate);
        }
```